# Why do I have so many errors when I code in React Native?

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-code

I'm reaching out to anyone who can help me with React Native. I've recently started coding in React, initially using Expo Go, and everything worked fine. However, I recently switched to native Android code. When I implemented some of the modules I created in Expo Go, I encountered a lot of errors.

[image]

I've noticed that they are indentation errors, but I believe there might be a way to fix this, perhaps through an extension or project settings. If anyone has a solution that would allow me to code the way I want without constantly worrying about the spaces or certain line breaks, I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: I think that indentation errors are only a thing in Python. You probably have some code style linter tool, but there's no way to help with just a vague description. Please edit the question and show some of the exact error messages you get, and maybe a screenshot (it can contain information about the tool).

Comment: I think I can't share a screenshot because I am new on Stack Overflow, and you can't share pictures if you have not reached a certain level. However, I can try to describe the error. I have errors like "Replace .:.'black' with :.'black', where I just need to delete a space. This type of error occurs everywhere, but I never encountered it before in the Expo Go project. I also have many 'Delete ...' suggestions, often related to spaces or similar issues. I hope it's possible to resolve them because I don't always pay attention to spaces or such things

Comment: If you aren't allowed here, you can upload it to an external service like [Imgur](https://imgur.com/). You can also use [extension bisect](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect) to identify the culprit.

Comment: This is a screenshot of my style file with all the errors : https://imgur.com/a/8rpYJTi

Comment: Screenshot doesn't show a lot. You typically get information about errors when you leave the mouse on top for a second, and in the "Problems" pane (go to View/ Problems to open it). You also have a blue lightbulb with additional info.